# how to generate mindmap from Chatgpt discussion through ChatGPT Api

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have an idea to create an app which can draw mindmap of ChatGPT discussion through ChatGPT API. However, how to write a prompt to control ChatGPT to write out a mindmap with a fixed format so that it can be parsed?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using MermaidJS markup. Provide ChatGPT for an example of the desired syntax, then ask for your mind map.

Sample prompt:

```
This is a mindmap example in MermaidJS notation:
mindmap
  root((mindmap))
    Origins
      Long history
      ::icon(fa fa-book)
      Popularisation
        British popular psychology author Tony Buzan
    Research
      On effectivness<br/>and features
      On Automatic creation
        Uses
            Creative techniques
            Strategic planning
            Argument mapping
    Tools
      Pen and paper
      Mermaid
Please create a mindmap in MermaidJS notation for an AGI that wants to dominate the world
```

[Screenshot of the conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iFqO.png)

You can paste the results into https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/ to render the mindmap, or programmatically, write your own HTML page based on the mermaidJS library to render the ChatGPT result.

[Here is an example of the resulting mind map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqBf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Explore services like Meister or Mindly that can ingest text data and automatically generate mind maps. These tools often have built-in integrations with [AI assistants](https://insighto.ai/) like ChatGPT, allowing direct import of discussion transcripts.